# sql - oracle - selecting the first and last record for specific group/sku

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been trying to come up for answer but no success.

**Need to get:** price for the first purchase and price for the last purchase and grouped by SKU.

Query results should be like this:

```
sku      first_purchase_price      Last_purchase_price   
BC123    3.09                      6.68    
QERT1    9.09                      13.23
```

**My Query**

```
SELECT sku,PRICE,MAX(purchase_DATE),MIN (purchase_DATE)
FROM store
ORDER By sku
```

**keep getting:**

```
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

*or*

```
SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SKU     TRANSAC_ID  purchase_DATE      PRICE
----------------------------------------------
BC123   CHI0018089  21-OCT-09          6.98
BC123   CHI0031199  11-MAR-13          6.68 
BC123   NAP1000890  22-JAN-08          3.09 
BC123   NAP1011123  21-DEC-11          89.9 
QQQ789  NAP1000891  22-JAN-08          4.01 
QERT1   JOL0400090  8-MAR-12           13.23 
QERT1   NAP1000990  22-FEB-08          9.09 
QERT1   NAP1001890  28-FEB-09          2.09 
WW000   CHI0031208  11-MAR-13          200.01 
WW000   CHI0031298  11-MAR-13          200.01 
YZV11   JOL0200080  10-OCT-06          230.23 
YZV11   AUR0700979  14-APR-13          6.68 
YZV11   CHI0018189  03-OCT-09          556.98 
YZV11   JOL0300080  10-MAR-11          300
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of [FIRST/LAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions065.htm#SQLRF51413) aggregate functions to
simplify this type of query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9ea1/1)

**Query**:

```
select
        sku,
        max(price) keep (dense_rank first order by purchase_date) first_purchase_price,
        max(price) keep (dense_rank last order by purchase_date) last_purchase_price
from
        store
group by
        sku;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9ea1/1/0)**:

```
|    SKU | FIRST_PURCHASE_PRICE | LAST_PURCHASE_PRICE |
|--------|----------------------|---------------------|
|  BC123 |                 3.09 |                6.68 |
|  QERT1 |                 9.09 |               13.23 |
| QQQ789 |                 4.01 |                4.01 |
|  WW000 |               200.01 |              200.01 |
|  YZV11 |               230.23 |                6.68 |
```

Comment: thank you Eat A Peach!!!!!!!!!!! you solved it the quickest shortest way.........!!!! it works on my side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your query is missing a GROUP BY clause indeed, if your intention is to
obtain the maximum and minimum "purchase_DATE" values for a certain value of "sku".
You need to group the columns you're referring to obtain the maximum and minimum values.
With the sample data above, you could try this query:

```
SELECT sku, MAX(purchase_DATE), MIN (purchase_DATE)
FROM store
GROUP BY sku
ORDER by sku
```

that would give you the max and min purchase dates for each SKU value, like:

```
BC123   2013-03-11  2000-01-22   -- max and min "purchase dates" for "BC123" sku
QERT1   2012-03-08  2008-02-22   -- ...                              "QERT1" sku
QQQ789  2008-01-22  2008-01-22   -- ...                             "QQQ789" sku
...                                 ...                                ...
```

If you would like the minimum and maximum prices for a certain "sku", you could use a very similar query.

Comment: yes i did want the first and last price for each sku. Thank you for this input!!! and propmt response.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT SKU, MAX(PURCHASE_DATE) MAXDATE, MIN(PURCHASE_DATE) MINDATE
FROM STORE
GROUP BY SKU
)
SELECT DISTINCT CTE.SKU, MINVAL.PRICE MINPRICE, MAXVAL.PRICE MAXPRICE
FROM STORE MINVAL, STORE MAXVAL, CTE
WHERE
CTE.SKU = MINVAL.SKU
AND CTE.MINDATE = MINVAL.PURCHASE_DATE
AND CTE.SKU = MAXVAL.SKU
AND CTE.MAXDATE = MAXVAL.PURCHASE_DATE
ORDER BY SKU
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9ea1/15)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with cte as
(select distinct sku,
 min(purchase_date) over (partition by sku order by sku) mindate,
 max(purchase_date) over (partition by sku order by sku) maxdate
 from store)

select distinct c.sku, 
smin.price first_purchase_price, 
smax.price last_purchase_price
from cte c
inner join store smin on c.mindate = smin.purchase_date and c.sku = smin.sku
inner join store smax on c.maxdate = smax.purchase_date and c.sku = smax.sku
order by c.sku
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19e9d/9)